# R: calculating population standard deviation with NA

Tags: r

As `sd` calculates sample standard deviation, not population standard deviation, I had to write a function to get the population standard deviation.

When there is no `NA`, it can be done easily as below.

```
> set.seed(1)
> mf1<-matrix(sample(c(10:100),18, replace=T),ncol=3)
> mf1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   34   95   72
[2,]   43   70   44
[3,]   62   67   80
[4,]   92   15   55
[5,]   28   28   75
[6,]   91   26  100
> pop.sd<-function(x){sqrt(sum((x-mean(x))^2)/length(x))}
> apply(mf1,1,pop.sd)
[1] 25.152866 12.498889  7.586538 31.443070 22.156012 32.967998
```

However, when there are NAs, the function returns NA for the corresponding row.

```
> mf2<-mf1
> mf2[c(2,5),3]<-NA
> mf2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   34   95   72
[2,]   43   70   NA
[3,]   62   67   80
[4,]   92   15   55
[5,]   28   28   NA
[6,]   91   26  100
> apply(mf2, 1, pop.sd)
[1] 25.152866        NA  7.586538 31.443070        NA 32.967998
```

Could you help me to make the function allow NAs so that I can have some numbers for the 2nd and 5th rows as well?

Thanks.

Comment: What should the standard deviation of a set of numbers be if some of them are missing?

Comment: @Hugh They should be 13.5 and 0.

Comment: You miss my point. In general, you should seek to understand why the values are missing, rather than simply excluding them when calculating `pop.sd`. If you say the second value should be 0, that entails the [5,3] value was 28.

Comment: @Hugh Good question, but it is beyond my question. I technically needed how to calculate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `na.rm=TRUE` in the `mean` and `sum` to account for the NA elements.

```
pop.sd<-function(x){sqrt(sum((x-mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))^2, 
                                 na.rm=TRUE)/sum(!is.na(x)))}
apply(mf2, 1, pop.sd)
#[1] 25.152866 13.500000  7.586538 31.443070  0.000000 32.967998
```

This should also give the same result for 'mf1'

```
apply(mf1,1,pop.sd)
#[1] 25.152866 12.498889  7.586538 31.443070 22.156012 32.967998
```

---

Instead of looping over the rows, we can also us the vectorized `rowSums` and `rowMeans`

```
sqrt(rowSums((mf1-rowMeans(mf1, na.rm=TRUE))^2, na.rm=TRUE)/ncol(mf1))
#[1] 25.152866 12.498889  7.586538 31.443070 22.156012 32.967998

sqrt(rowSums((mf2-rowMeans(mf2, na.rm=TRUE))^2, na.rm=TRUE)/ncol(mf2))
#[1] 25.152866 11.022704  7.586538 31.443070  0.000000 32.967998
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As I didn't get to put `na.rm` in both mean and sum before (I only tried to put `na.rm` at the end of the function), your comment gave me a great insight for that. But, as length(x) does not account for NA (it returns 3 for all rows), the standard deviations from the function you suggested were not correct.

Comment: @ShinziKatoh I changed the `length(x)` to `sum(!is.na(x))`, but still it gives the same result

Comment: @ShinziKatoh Please let me know the logic for your calcuation.

Comment: The solution changing `length(x)` to '`sum(!is.na(x)` works very well. Because only 2nd and 5th rows have NAs, all results other than the 2 rows should be the same. As you can see, the sd for the 2nd row changed from 11.022704 (obtained by using `length(x)`to 13.50000 (obtained by using `sum(!is.na(x)`. The result for 5th row should be zero because all elements were the same. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @ShinziKatoh Yes, my solution gives the output you wanted.  Thank you for the feedback.